# Eclipse Debugger Goes to Library Classes

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, step-into

Just debugging a project using Eclipse Luna 4.4.0, when using the debugger, upon reaching my breakpoint, and hence using the "step into" button, it takes me to generic Library classes such as Threads.class etc.. I'm pretty sure it's a problem with my Eclipse configuration, as it was working perfectly fine on a different machine, but since switching it's become a real pain having to step over a fair few Library classes before I can get back to my own code.

Any help with what to change would be extremely helpful, thanks.

Comment: use "step over", not "step into", when you run into a "not my code" method call.

Comment: This is what I have been doing, was just wondering if there's a way to stop it going in to all these other classes to begin with?

Comment: not when you're debugging by stepping through. If you just want to hit specific points, you can use breakpoint based debugging and simply "keep running" after every breakpoint inspection.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what your goal is (you shouldn't just ignore library classes while debugging simply by virtue of them being library), but there's a `Step filter` page under `Preferences -> Java -> Debug` that might help you out [*Link here*](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-usestepfilters.htm)

Answer (score 3):

You can use step filtering to skip certain packages/classes when debugging. If you have *additional* packages in your project you'll need to add those packages to Step Filtering.

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Debug -> "Add Packages"

Select all the packages that you want to skip during debugging. Use shift to select multiple packages. Click OK and ensure that they are checked.

See [this](https://dzone.com/articles/step-filtering-skip-certain) article for further clarification.